# What is the Calvinist view of Christians with different levels of loving God?

Tags: reformed-theology, free-will, love

A) Scripture says no force or power can separate us from the Love of God.

> "For I am persuaded, that neither death, nor life, nor angels, nor principalities, nor powers, nor things present, nor things to come, Nor height, nor depth, nor any other creature, shall be able to separate us from the love of God, which is in Christ Jesus our Lord. - Romans 8:38-39

B) Some Christians are more separated from the love God (i.e. they love God less than others).

If nothing can separate us from God, then why are some Christians more separated from God's love? What is the deciding factor in how much we love God?

I suppose the non-Calvinist response would be "our will": Our own love of sin / self-will is what separates us since God's love for us does not change.

#### Possible answer(?)

Some people have a different level of Faith (from God)

> "as God hath dealt to every man the measure of faith. - Romans 12:3

and more/less Sin

> "He who is forgiven much loves much" Luke 7:47

However, scripture says faith comes by hearing:

> "So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God. - Romans 10:17

This seems to put the burden back on people to decide to "listen" or "sin more" which isn't inline with Reformed theology.

Comment: The idea that nothing can seperate us from the love of God, i believe is generally understood to mean that nothing can come between God's love towards us, not our love toward God